# Audacity - cut without repositioning.

Tags: editing, audio-recording

Using Audacity if I trim an audio track the remaining audio is shifted to the left. I want it to stay in position since it is in time with another track. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command you are looking for is Split Delete (Ctrl+Alt+K).

This will split the audio at the beginning and end of your selection and delete the middle.

Comment: On OSX:  Command+Alt+k